# Open file from route in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have developed a Node module which needs a configuration file (CSV).
I am trying to use this module within an Express Route module. 
The problem is that the module fails to load the configuration file.

What kind of Path should I use? relative to the module? relative to the route? relative to the express project folder?

Comment: You might be right.

Comment: Which outside module you use? If it is written by yourself, could you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the path module to resolve the relative path

```
    var url="/relativeDir1/relativeDir2";
    var pathModule = require("path");
    var path =  pathModule.resolve(path.join(__dirname, url));
```